# Strange syntax error with theano

Tags: python, syntax, function-declaration

I'm trying to use theano in my code right now in python 3.4. However, there are many function with the following strange syntax

```
def c_code(self, node, name, (var1, var2), (var3,), sub):
...
```

i.e. they have brackets within the function definition.

Python throws a syntax error on them

> File ".../Theano-0.7.0/theano/scalar/basic.py", line 1011
>   def c_code(self, node, name, (var1, var2), (var3, ), sub):
>                                   ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Now, once I remove those extra brackets, everything works great, but I'm new to python and noticed there were a lot of changes in python 3 so these brackets may need to be replaced with something else rather than removed.

Can someone explain to me (a) what having brackets inside function definition means? and (b) if and how can these be made to work with python 3?

Comment: Seems like that's valid syntax in Python 2.x, but not in Python 3. It means that the third parameter is a two-elemented tuple that's automatically unpacked as `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuple argument unpacking has been removed in Python 3.0 via [PEP3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/):

> **Tuple parameter unpacking** is the use of a tuple as a parameter in a
>   function signature so as to have a sequence argument automatically
>   unpacked. An example is:
>
> ```
> def fxn(a, (b, c), d):
>     pass
> ```
>
> The use of `(b, c)` in the signature requires that the second argument to the function be a sequence of length two (e.g., `[42, -13]`
>   ). When such a sequence is passed it is unpacked and has its values
>   assigned to the parameters, just as if the statement `b, c = [42, -13]`
>   had been executed in the parameter.
>
> Unfortunately this feature of Python's rich function signature
>   abilities, while handy in some situations, causes more issues than
>   they are worth. Thus this PEP proposes their removal from the language
>   in Python 3.0.

So if you take this function signature

```
def fun(foo, (a, b, c), bar):
    pass
```

then that is equivalent to

```
def fun(foo, arg, bar):
    a, b, c = arg
    pass
```

so that's the way you would achieve the same behavior with Python 3.x.

However, since this is not your own code base, I don't see an easy way of addressing that (short of monkey patching), and there might also be more Python 3 incompatibilities that aren't as easily spotted as `SyntaxError`s.

---

Interestingly enough, [issue #783](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/783) linked by @tobias_k has been closed, and from it it seems that Python 3 support has been addressed and finished. Also, Theano *does* [claim Python 3 support according to it's Trove classifiers](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/setup.py#L48-L50).

However, the version you're using (0.7.0) is the most recently released one, and the function signature you encountered is in fact [still to be found on current `master`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/scalar/basic.py#L1011). So - this is a bug, you should probably file an issue on [Theano's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues).

Comment: so patching fun(foo, (a,b,c), bar) to fun(foo,a,b,c,bar) isn't a good idea?

Comment: @WhiteTiger the problem is, that alone won't work, because chances are there is other code in Theano that uses that function and that expects the old function signature. And I was wrong, not even monkey patching the function and wrapping it would work, because the old signature is still there, and still is invalid syntax in Python 3, so it won't even compile.

Comment: @WhiteTiger if I just browse through [that module](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/scalar/basic.py) on github, there's *a ton* of other functions that use tuple unpacking. So it seems they only really made an effort to achieve Python 3 compatibility once, but didn't stick with it, and fell back to using old patterns.

Comment: @WhiteTiger the `2to3` module seems to have a [fixer for tuple parameter unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-tuple_params) that basically applies the change I outlined above. So you could try yourself to port the `Theano` codebase to Python3 again, but honestly, I don't think your chances are good. If the missed all those syntax errors, it means 1) they have no tests for Py3 and 2) none of the devs use Py3, so you're very likely to hit many more incompatibilities.